# Why every page show the index page?

Tags: go

i'm creating a small website from scratch, it's been some times since my last website in go and I remeber using the same code i'm using now and it worked without issues. I don't get why, now , it doesn't work, already tried clearing cookies.
Every page return the index template.
That's the code:

**EDIT:** Removed "http.Handle("/", r)" nothing changes

```
var tpl *template.Template


func MainHandling() {
r := http.NewServeMux()

r.HandleFunc("/", Index)
r.HandleFunc("/login", Login)
r.HandleFunc("/register", Register)


fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./1Forum/static/")) // funziona solo con newservemux
r.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", fs))

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", context.ClearHandler(r)))
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
}

func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "login.html", nil)
}

func Register(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "register.html", nil)
}
```

Comment: There's too many unknowns in your code; you should provide a [mcve] if you want help, otherwise it will not be possible to suggest accurate solutions unless someone here ran code closely similar to your's and encountered, and was able to resolve, the same exact issue.

Comment: I mean that's the only logic in the program, .html files are just different pages with only html code. Files are all in the same folder and it isn't a structure problem as index have no problem displaying. Must be a logic problem.

Comment: What's `http.Handle("/", r)` for? Try removing it. But your code even as shown should work. The issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: @rustyx Removed but nothing changed.  I don't get where could be the problem because that's the only logic of the program

Comment: Do the calls to ExecuteTemplate return an error? How is tpl initialized?

Comment: For all we know all the html files could contain the same content. For all we know `MainHandling` is never actually called by `main` and some other handlers are being initialized. For all we know `tpl.ExecuteTemplate` fails with an error, or it's uninitialized and all the handlers panic and there's a recovery middleware somewhere. For all we know `context.ClearHandler` returns a handler that serves only `index.html`. As I already said, first provide an example that can be used to reproduce the problem, then we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The `"/"` pattern matches everything, so you need to check that you are at the root:

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        return
    }
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
}
```

Check [reference](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux.Handle) for more information.